# How to Check MAXDOP configuration in Azure Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How to check MAXDOP configurations in Azure Dedicated SQL Pool using SQL queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the configuration using below command

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations
```

[image]

And alter the same using

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 1
```

Make sure you have the right permissions.

Comment: Don't put image containing sensitive information like azure sql service name in the public forum